# SQL error inserting into table

Tags: php, mysql

I keep getting this error in my php. It worked fine when I hard set the values but doesn't seem to work with variables.

> Error: INSERT INTO ContactUS (name, email, subscribed) VALUES (TEST, my@email.com, 1)
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Anis, my@email.com, 1)' at line 1

```
// Create connection
            $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
            // Check connection
            if ($conn->connect_error) {
                die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
            } 

            $sql = "INSERT INTO ContactUS (name, email, subscribed) VALUES ($name, $email, $subscribed)";

            if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                echo "New record created successfully";
            } else {
                echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
            }
```

Comment: `VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$subscribed')`, but this leaves open to sql injection. Read this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/711206).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Values should be quoted:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO ContactUS (name, email, subscribed) VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$subscribed')";
```

Perhaps it's better to use *prepared statements* as this is done automatically for you **and** you won't be vulnerable to [SQL injections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: You should change your second sentence to `It is better to use prepared statements as this is done automatically for you, and you won't be open to SQL injections.`

Comment: Ah thanks I assumed because they were variables they did not need quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Use quotes around variables, as PHP will replace its value, leaving an invalid query:

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO ContactUS (name, email, subscribed) VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$subscribed')";
```

but please use prepared statements, otherwise you'll be victim of SQL injection

Comment: Your answer should state what your changed so the OP knows the issue in the future.